# How to type cast for my use case in Dart 2

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to clean-up some (working) code on a fork of the [Flutter Architecture Samples](https://github.com/mmcc007/flutter_architecture_samples) github project. Does anyone familiar with casting in Dart 2 have any suggestions on how to clean up my attempt?

This may change after posting, but what I currently have is:

```
Stream<List<TodoEntity>> todos() {
  return firebase.reference().child(path).onValue.map((event) {
    if (event.snapshot == null || event.snapshot.value == null) return [];
    return Map
      .castFrom(event.snapshot.value.map((key, doc) {
        return MapEntry(
            key,
            TodoEntity(
              doc['task'],
              key,
              doc['note'] ?? '',
              doc['complete'] ?? false,
            ));
      }))
      .values
      .toList()
      .cast();
    });
}
```

I'm casting multiple times, I expect I can remove the `.cast()` and be more explicit about the types so the compiler knows what to do and it is easier to read and understand.

The complete code can currently be found on my [fork](https://github.com/mmcc007/flutter_architecture_samples/blob/master/example/firebase_rtdb_flutter_repository/lib/reactive_todos_repository.dart)

btw: the [flutter_redux](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/tree/master/example/firestore_redux) flutter app works with [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I have added support to enable it to work with [firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), including tests.

edit:
Thanks to [Rémi Rousselet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8394265/r%C3%A9mi-rousselet), the following works without casting:

```
Stream<List<TodoEntity>> todos() {
  return firebase.reference().child(path).onValue.map((event) {
    if (event.snapshot == null || event.snapshot.value == null) return [];
    final Map<dynamic, dynamic> value = event.snapshot.value;
    final todoMap = value.map((key, doc) {
      return MapEntry(
        key,
        TodoEntity(
          doc['task'],
          key,
          doc['note'] ?? '',
          doc['complete'] ?? false,
        ));
    });
    return todoMap.values.toList();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can remove a lot more than just the last `cast` and have type check too.

```
final Map<String, dynamic> value;
final foo = value.map((key, doc) {
  return MapEntry(
      key,
      TodoEntity(
        doc['task'],
        key,
        doc['note'] ?? '',
        doc['complete'] ?? false,
      ));
});
final values = foo.values.toList();
```

Dart will automatically infere the type accordingly. So that `foo` is of type `Map<String, TodoEntity>` and `values` of type `List<TodoEntity>`

Comment: Had to change `Map<String, dynamic> value` to `Map<dynamic, dynamic> value`. Other than that it worked! Thnx.